# Apache 2.4 - Request exceeded the limit of 100 internal redirects due to probable configuration error

Tags: laravel, apache

I'm running Apache 2.4 (64bit) and PHP 7.1 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise and have noticed the following error in the Apache error log which produces an HTTP error 500 on all pages except the homepage:

```
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 100 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

I think the error is coming from an error in the htaccess rewrites and I have looked at similar posts but have been unable to determine which strategy to follow. Here's a sample of my .htaccess public domain:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

The error came out of all of a sudden and while I'm able to access my-site.com, I cannot access any of my-site.com/page.
Can anyone suggest what I need to change?